# How to disable anonymous urls hitting the application

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

Taking following as an exacmple.
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

On it's browser, If I type
https://bnpsd.csb.app/abcd/efgh/567

I still see the menus and the application loaded. What really need is make it not going to the allocation. I know that can add not found page. But, instead what I need is to make it not going to the application.

Is there anyway this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> But, instead what I need is to make it not going to the application.

This a problematic desire. Since you cannot completely control the URL (the user can type what she wants) you *must* respond with something.

There is no difference between a URL that finds no content and a URL that finds no route — both should become *404 Not Found*.

You *can* actually differentiate between missing routes (add a “catch all” `<Route>` component at the end of a `<Switch>`) and missing content (add specific error management when data fails to be fetched from the server) but IMHO it is not a worthwhile road to take.